# Passing Integer to int and vice versa

Tags: java

Just wondered why is it possible to pass Integer as argument where method parameter is of int type and vice versa?

```
public class Salmon {

 public static Integer foo(Integer a, int b){
  return a - b;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Integer a = 10;
  int b = 1;
  foo(b, a);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is *auto-boxing* and *auto-unboxing*. Basically the compiler puts in calls to `Integer.valueOf()` or `x.intValue()` appropriately.

The exact mechanism isn't actually specified, but the relevant sections of the spec are [5.1.7 and 5.1.8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7).

Comment: It should be noted that this feature brings with it a class of mysterious NullPointerException problems.

Comment: Could you develop ? In which case would this threw a NullPointerException ?

Comment: @mxdsp: That's not part of the question at all. If you're running into an NPE you can't explain, please ask a new question after doing *thorough* research. (There are *lots* of questions on NPEs.)

Comment: Sorry If I'm out of topic but I was reacting to @Pointy comment, and I can't see how this is not related to the question. I'm not running into any NPE (yet), but I'm wondering in which case auto-(un)boxing **can't** be use safely because it might "brings mysterious NPE"

Comment: @mxdsp: Ah, that makes sense. In future, it's worth adding an appropriate "@" so it's obvious who you're replying to. (Although I should have spotted it in this case - my bad.) Autounboxing can be confusing around the conditional operator - that's the place I've most commonly seen NPEs.

Comment: @mxdsp the NPE problem is about *unboxing*, but the way the language works makes it "mysterious" because it's doesn't necessarily fail immediately. A `null` Integer (capital-I) cannot really be "unboxed" because there can't be a 'null' int (little-I) value, for example. Attempts to reference a failed unboxing trigger the NPE.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet & @Pointy, this really helps. I used a code qualimetry tool to replace "unnecessary Constructors" for Integers and Strings with new values inside methods call (replaced for instance `Integer(1)` with 1`), I guess in that case, a null value can't occurs but I'll double check that.